# Reemplazar una parte de una cadena con otra en JAVA

Tags: java, string

tengo un problema muy particular y me gustaría recibir la ayuda de uds, el problema es el siguiente:
Tengo que llegar de esta cadena:

```
<mrk mid="0" mtype="seg">A <g id="1">model</g> is a group of files that are stored in a directory in the <g id="2">central repository</g>.</mrk> <mrk mid="1" mtype="seg">The <g id="3">model</g> defines how an <g id="4">engine</g> of the <g id="5">Corporate Service</g> (26) will work.</mrk>
```

a esta:

```
<mrk mid="0" mtype="seg">A <g id="1">model</g> is a group of files that are stored in a directory in the <g id="2">central repository</g>.</mrk> <mrk mid="1" mtype="seg">The <g id="3">model</g> defines how an <g id="4">engine</g> of [[otro]] <g id="5"></g> (26) will work.</mrk>
```

tengo como informacion que tengo que sustituir  "the Corporate Service" por "[[otro]]" manteniendo las etiquetas XML que puedan haber en medio siguiendo el fortamo: [[cadena a sustituir]][etiquetas] , en este caso `[[otro]] <g id="5">`, como ven no es un simple .replace, en realidad me he quedado sin ideas....espero que alguien pueda ayudarme, por cierto uso JAVA. Gracias de antemano

Comment: Si formateas tu xml correctamente te entenderemos mejor, edita tu pregunta y escribe tu xml como un xml, que leerlo como esta ahora es engorroso

Comment: te recomiendo leer el ar´ticulo [Te he votado negativamente porque no intentaste nada](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2874/)